As demanded by Google, since I moved to `targetSdkVersion` 34 (from 33) , my app crashes
I bubbled up my targetSdkVersion to 34 from 33 and the result is a quasi immediate crash (The whole crash report at the end of the question).
It looks like there is an issue with signatures:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package com.olenergies.olenpepsmobile signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!]

And one related to Streams:

The following PlatformException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android:
PlatformException(error, com.olenergies.olenpepsmobile: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts, null, null)

I am a bit puzzled and would appreciate help to put me on the right track.
The whole log:
Launching lib/main.dart on Pixel 7 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/stephanedeluca/development/OlenPEPS-mobile/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Existing package com.olenergies.olenpepsmobile signatures do not match newer version; ignoring!]

Uninstalling old version...
D/FlutterBluePlugin(19617): onAttachedToEngine
D/FlutterBluePlugin(19617): setup
D/FlutterBluePlugin(19617): onAttachedToActivity
D/FlutterGeolocator(19617): Attaching Geolocator to activity
D/FlutterGeolocator(19617): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(19617): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(19617): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator(19617): Initializing Geolocator services
D/FlutterGeolocator(19617): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:50826/bAf0OsM1Bl8=/ws
I/flutter (19617): Geolocator status: subscribing to stream
I/flutter (19617): Reading package information…
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617): Failed to open event stream
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617): java.lang.SecurityException: com.olenergies.olenpepsmobile: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3183)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3167)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3150)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3092)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.registerReceiverWithFeature(IActivityManager.java:5860)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1853)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1793)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1781)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:757)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at com.baseflow.geolocator.LocationServiceHandlerImpl.onListen(LocationServiceHandlerImpl.java:58)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler.onListen(EventChannel.java:218)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.EventChannel$IncomingStreamRequestHandler.onMessage(EventChannel.java:197)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617): Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.registerReceiverWithFeature(ActivityManagerService.java:14467)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2648)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2822)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1500)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1444)
E/EventChannel#flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android(19617):
W/Activity(19617): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): onRequestPermissionsResult: arguments (1452, [Ljava.lang.String;@decb7e2, [I@89d5773)
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): requestPermissionCookie: {}
W/Activity(19617): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): onRequestPermissionsResult: arguments (6567854, [Ljava.lang.String;@1957630, [I@fc622a9)
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): requestPermissionCookie: {6567854=Function1<int[], java.lang.Boolean>}
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): permissionResultCallback: args([I@fc622a9)
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(19617): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.
W/WindowOnBackDispatcher(19617): Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.

════════ Exception caught by services library ══════════════════════════════════
The following PlatformException was thrown while activating platform stream on channel flutter.baseflow.com/geolocator_service_updates_android:
PlatformException(error, com.olenergies.olenpepsmobile: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts, null, null)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:651:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:322:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      EventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:664:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (19617): Read the information 1.3.16
I/flutter (19617): WiFi scanner: CanGetScannedResults.noLocationPermissionRequired
I/flutter (19617): Geolocator status: inital value for _isLocationEnabled is true
W/Activity(19617): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): onRequestPermissionsResult: arguments (109, [Ljava.lang.String;@8e9613a, [I@3da41eb)
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): requestPermissionCookie: {6567854=Function1<int[], java.lang.Boolean>}
I/Geolocator(19617): The grantResults array is empty. This can happen when the user cancels the permission request
I/flutter (19617): An error occured while trying to get your device location: User denied permissions to access the device's location.
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(19617): Compat change id reported: 78294732; UID 10467; state: ENABLED
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): onRequestPermissionsResult: arguments (24, [Ljava.lang.String;@f900819, [I@f2140de)
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): requestPermissionCookie: {6567854=Function1<int[], java.lang.Boolean>}
I/flutter (19617): Location permission is granted
I/flutter (19617): Location when in use permission is granted
I/flutter (19617): Geolocator status: subscribing to stream
I/flutter (19617): Reading package information…
I/flutter (19617): Read the information 1.3.16
I/flutter (19617): Location permission is granted
I/flutter (19617): Geolocator status: inital value for _isLocationEnabled is true
I/flutter (19617): Start scanning ble devices nearby…
I/flutter (19617): SCANNING: false
W/Activity(19617): Can request only one set of permissions at a time
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): onRequestPermissionsResult: arguments (1454, [Ljava.lang.String;@ffc8cea, [I@8737bdb)
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): requestPermissionCookie: {6567854=Function1<int[], java.lang.Boolean>}
I/flutter (19617): isScanning: true
I/flutter (19617): isScanning: true
I/flutter (19617): Location when in use permission is granted
I/flutter (19617): ➜ Translation key in 'en_us' is missing: "1Un appareil bluetooth analyséM%d appareils bluetooth analysés".
I/flutter (19617): ➜ Translation key in 'en_us' is missing: "1Un appareil bluetooth analyséM%d appareils bluetooth analysés".
I/flutter (19617): Dispose (Geolocator status: )
I/flutter (19617): Stop scanning ble devices nearby
D/BluetoothAdapter(19617): isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(19617): could not find callback wrapper
I/flutter (19617): Done stopScan()
I/flutter (19617): isScanning: false
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): onRequestPermissionsResult: arguments (1453, [Ljava.lang.String;@a57cc90, [I@f162989)
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): requestPermissionCookie: {6567854=Function1<int[], java.lang.Boolean>}
D/FlutterBluePlugin(19617): mDevices size: 0
I/flutter (19617): Scanning connected devices: found 0
I/flutter (19617): Start scanning ble devices nearby…
I/flutter (19617): SCANNING: false
I/flutter (19617): isScanning: true
I/flutter (19617): ➜ Translation key in 'en_us' is missing: "1Un appareil bluetooth analyséM%d appareils bluetooth analysés".
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): onRequestPermissionsResult: arguments (1455, [Ljava.lang.String;@3ca049a, [I@38711cb)
D/WifiScanPlugin(19617): requestPermissionCookie: {6567854=Function1<int[], java.lang.Boolean>}
D/BluetoothAdapter(19617): isLeEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(19617): onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=8 mScannerId=0
D/AndroidRuntime(19617): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(19617): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(19617): Process: com.olenergies.olenpepsmobile, PID: 19617
E/AndroidRuntime(19617): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at com.boskokg.flutter_blue_plus.FlutterBluePlusPlugin$2.onScanResult(FlutterBluePlusPlugin.java:1045)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper$1.run(BluetoothLeScanner.java:568)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UUID string too large
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at java.util.UUID.fromStringJava11(UUID.java:238)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:226)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    at com.boskokg.flutter_blue_plus.ProtoMaker.<clinit>(ProtoMaker.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(19617):    ... 10 more
I/Process (19617): Sending signal. PID: 19617 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.

Exited.


This question is similar to: One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Step 1: Check in the all project if you register a receiver:
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

Step 2: Update to be compatible with Android 14+
You can follow how to update in this post:

 

One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
Step 3:
Check one by one each library and update to the lastest version. It is neccesary because the librariers can also have the the receiver integrated on their source code.

Aditional Info:
 Check the manifest merged and look for which library has a receiver. after you identify, update the library.

Example of the android native project:
https://prnt.sc/BXODTuUsa-KW

goto ProtoMaker.java:35
and delete the word "static"
it works for me using flutter_blue, and upgraded to SDK 34
^_^

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
